# ¿Como mostrar un rango de inicio y final agrupados por estados en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subconsultas

Tengo una tabla llamada documentos con tres registros id, numero, estado. Lo que deseo hacer, es obtener una consulta con los intervalos (min y max), para cada registro.

Para ser mas descriptivo si la tabla la relleno, con lo siguientes datos:

```
    | numero | estado
    | 1      | 1
    | 2      | 1
    | 3      | 1
    | 4      | 0
    | 5      | 0
    | 6      | 1
    | 7      | 1
```

Inicialmente utilizaba la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT MIN(numero) AS inicio,
       MAX(numero) AS final,
       estado
FROM documentos
GROUP BY estado
```

El resultado de la consulta es:

```
    | min | max | estado
    |  4  |  5  |  0
    |  1  |  7  |  1
```

Pero se que la query está mala, ya que lo que deseo es:

```
    | min | max | estado
    | 4   | 5   | 0
    | 1   | 3   | 1
    | 6   | 7   | 1
```

Es decir, mostrar un rango de inicio y final agrupados por estados.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo, le agradecería bastante,
desde ya, gracias por su atención,

Comment: Qué significado tiene el ID? Por convención esa debiera ser una llave única y opcionalmente autoincremental. ¿Es el número un campo único autoincremental?

Comment: voy a sacar el id, para no confundirse, no tiene relevancia con lo que deseo llegar.

Comment: pero se que existe, por ejemplo aquí obtengo el rango de numeros consecutivos faltantes:
SELECT a.numero+1 AS inicio, MIN(b.numero) - 1 AS fin
FROM   documentos AS a, documentos AS b
WHERE  a.numero < b.numero
GROUP  BY a.numero HAVING inicio < MIN(b.numero);

Pero para el caso de la pregunta, he tratado de hacerlo, pero aun no puedo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mostrar un rango de inicio y final agrupados por estados.

Solo para aclarar lo que pides. En realidad no estás simplemente tratando de agrupar por `estado`, porque de ser el caso, tu consulta y resultado originales serían las correctas.

Mas bien, por el resultado deseado, resulta obvio que lo que deseas en realidad es agrupar por *cambios de estado*. En otras palabras, asumiendo que los registros están ordenados por `numero`, cada vez que el valor de la columna `estado` cambia, esto se debe considerar como el comienzo de un nuevo agrupamiento de registros.

Normalmente, este tipo de consulta se arma usando funciones ventana, que MySQL no tiene.  Aun así, parece que con el uso de variables, es posible armar una consulta que parece ser mas eficiente de lo que esperaba, aunque sí es compleja:

```
set @groupId := 0;
select min(numero) as inicio,
       max(numero) as final,
       max(estado) as estado
  from (select numero,
               estado,
               (@groupId := @groupId + cambio_de_estado) as group_id
          from (select t1.numero,
                       t1.estado,
                       case when t1.estado = t2.estado
                            then 0 else 1 end as cambio_de_estado
                  from tbl t1
                  left join tbl t2 on t2.numero = t1.numero - 1
                 order by t1.numero
               ) t
        ) t
 group by group_id
 order by max(estado), group_id;
```

Resultado:

```
inicio   final   estado
  4        5       0
  1        3       1
  6        7       1
```

---

## Explicación por etapas

**1. Identificar dónde comienzan los intervalos**

Esto se logra por medio de la consulta siguiente:

```
select t1.numero,
       t1.estado,
       case when t1.estado = t2.estado
            then 0 else 1 end as cambio_de_estado
  from tbl t1
  left join tbl t2 on t2.numero = t1.numero - 1
 order by t1.numero
```

Que devuelve el resultado siguiente:

```
numero    estado     cambio_de_estado
  1         1              1
  2         1              0
  3         1              0
  4         0              1
  5         0              0
  6         1              1
  7         1              0
```

Esta hace un join con el registro anterior para determinar si hay un cambio de estado entre los 2 registros. Si lo hay, devolvemos `1` en la columna `cambio_de_estado` para identificar que esto es el comienzo de un intervalo.

**2. Asignar un id único a cada intervalo**

Esto se logra haciendo una suma cumulativa, lo que no se puede hacer en SQL puro con MySQL (se necesitan funciones ventana para esto), pero se puede simular con la ayuda de una variable:

```
set @groupId := 0;
select numero,
       estado,
       (@groupId := @groupId + cambio_de_estado) as group_id
  from (select t1.numero,
               t1.estado,
               case when t1.estado = t2.estado
                    then 0 else 1 end as cambio_de_estado
          from tbl t1
          left join tbl t2 on t2.numero = t1.numero - 1
         order by t1.numero
       ) t;
```

Resultado:

```
numero    estado     group_id
  1         1           1
  2         1           1
  3         1           1
  4         0           2
  5         0           2
  6         1           3
  7         1           3
```

**3. Agrupar por intervalo**

Una vez que finalmente tenemos un id único que podemos usar para identificar cada intervalo, es trivial usar un `GROUP BY` para obtener el resultado deseado:

```
set @groupId := 0;
select min(numero) as inicio,
       max(numero) as final,
       max(estado) as estado
  from (select numero,
               estado,
               (@groupId := @groupId + cambio_de_estado) as group_id
          from (select t1.numero,
                       t1.estado,
                       case when t1.estado = t2.estado
                            then 0 else 1 end as cambio_de_estado
                  from tbl t1
                  left join tbl t2 on t2.numero = t1.numero - 1
                 order by t1.numero
               ) t
        ) t
 group by group_id
 order by max(estado), group_id;
```

Resultado:

```
inicio   final   estado
  4        5       0
  1        3       1
  6        7       1
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta y bien explicado