# ¿Cómo asignador un identificador a una valor en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, subconsultas

Qué tal, no sé si mi pregunta es la correcta, no sé cómo expresarlo de la mejor manera, en fin, aquí está mi problema;

Tengo esta tabla con estos valores:

| CR | UR | NUMCHE | INSTRU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014870030 | FO2 | 100788834 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FO2 | 100788835 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FO2 | 100788836 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FO2 | 100788837 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FO3 | 100788838 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FO3 | 110089667 | 11 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 110089668 | 11 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788839 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788840 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788841 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788842 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 110089669 | 11 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788843 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788844 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788845 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 100788846 | 10 |
| 2014870030 | FOR | 120007756 | 12 |

Necesito agrupar estos registros en función de la columna INSTRU, pero, crear por grupos, es decir, mi consulta fue la siguiente:

```
SELECT emp.cr,emp.ur,emp.numche,emp.instru,MIN(numche) AS 'INICIO',MAX(numche) AS 'FINAL'
FROM for1421 emp 
INNER JOIN centros AS cr ON emp.CR = cr.CR  
WHERE emp.cr = '2014870030' AND emp.INSTRU != '00'
GROUP BY emp.cr,emp.INSTRU
```

Dándome como resultado el siguiente:

| cr | instru | INICIO | FINAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014870030 | 10 | 100788834 | 100788846 |
| 2014870030 | 11 | 110089667 | 110089669 |
| 2014870030 | 12 | 120007756 | 120007756 |

Sin embargo, como pueden notar en la primer tabla, lo datos vienen ordenados por la columna UR.
Pero, lo que busco es lo siguiente:

| cr | instru | INICIO | FINAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014870030 | 10 | 100788834 | 100788838 |
| 2014870030 | 11 | 110089667 | 110089668 |
| 2014870030 | 10 | 100788839 | 100788842 |
| 2014870030 | 11 | 110089669 | 110089669 |
| 2014870030 | 10 | 100788843 | 100788846 |
| 2014870030 | 12 | 120007756 | 120007756 |

Que agrupe los datos cada que cambie el valor de la columna 'INSTRU'

¿Cuál es mi propuesta? De alguna forma asignar otra columna con un identificador y cada que aparezca por ejemplo el instru 10 ponga el número 1 hasta que cambie al 11 y ponga el 2, cuando vuelva a salir el 10 que ahora coloque el 3 pero en este punto me quedé atorado.

He numerado pero lo hace de forma automática y usando un IF cambia los valores de forma igualitaria.
¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Me parece que a tus ejemplos les hace falta la columna UR para entender un poco mejor la relación con los valores __instru__, __inicio__ y __final__

Comment: Es irrelevante en los resultados, por eso ya no la mando a traer, viene en la tabla base porque así me la proporcionaron :D

Comment: Encontré lo que buscaba en este link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119011/como-mostrar-un-rango-de-inicio-y-final-agrupados-por-estados-en-mysql?rq=1 No sé si se pueda simplificar.

Comment: La pregunta es confusa: *Que agrupe los datos cada que cambie el valor de la columna 'INSTRU'* ¿Qué datos debe agrupar? Pon un ejemplo sencillo, no hace falta capturas de pantalla, con texto bastaría. Parecería que esto puede resolverse facil usando `GROUP_CONCAT()` y `GROUP BY`, **si se tratase de agrupar realmente**, cosa que dudo, porque en la salida deseada que muestras no veo que los datos estén realmente agrupados por la columna `instru` (aparecen varias filas con un mismo valor, entonces no estaríamos hablando de agrupar en el sentido propio de la palabra, no al menos por esa columna).